# WPF: Animate an inner element for fade in/fade out

Tags: c#, wpf, animation

I've been using WPF for about a week now. One of the controls I needed to implement was an aero style Windows Explorer like Treeview that was quite close to the original. I saw that the  original WPF treeview would need some theming to achieve that so I searched about on the Internet for a basic resource dictionary/theme that I could use. I found one and I've been adjusting it ever since. I made some progress however considering that I only begun working with WPF a week ago, I've hit a problem that I don't know how to solve.

You see, one of the behaviors of the 7 style explorer is that the expand/collapse toggle buttons fade in and out depending on whether one has focus on the it's treeview or the mouse is over it.

I tried to implement the behavior by applying it to the actual TreeView via a style and trigger (IsFocused) and performing an animation from there, but I do not know how to actually "address" the toggle buttons. They're also defined in another style. I've been trying to do it in XAML and would prefer it in XAML for simplicity's sake although I do not know if that is possible.

**Here is the resource Dictionary (well the important parts concerning tree view elements and my failed attempt):**

```
    <!-- Selected Hover Brushes -->
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="HoverSelectedBackgroundBrushKey"
                     StartPoint="0,0"
                     EndPoint="0,1">
    <GradientStop Color="#DCEBFC"
                  Offset="0" />
    <GradientStop Color="#C1DBFC"
                  Offset="1" />
</LinearGradientBrush>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="HoverSelectedOuterBorderBrushKey"
                 Color="#7DA2CE" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="HoverSelectedInnerBorderBrushKey"
                 Color="#EBF4FD" />

<!-- Hover Brushes -->
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="HoverBackgroundBrushKey"
                     StartPoint="0,0"
                     EndPoint="0,1">
    <GradientStop Color="#FCFCFC"
                  Offset="0" />
    <GradientStop Color="#EBF3FD"
                  Offset="1" />
</LinearGradientBrush>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="HoverOuterBorderBrushKey"
                 Color="#B8D6FB" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="HoverInnerBorderBrushKey"
                 Color="#F2F7FE" />

<!-- Selected (Active) Brushes -->
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="SelectedActiveBackgroundBrushKey"
                     StartPoint="0,0"
                     EndPoint="0,1">
    <GradientStop Color="#EAF3FE"
                  Offset="0" />
    <GradientStop Color="#CFE4FE"
                  Offset="1" />
</LinearGradientBrush>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="SelectedActiveOuterBorderBrushKey"
                 Color="#84ACDD" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="SelectedActiveInnerBorderBrushKey"
                 Color="#F1F7FE" />

<!-- Selected (Inactive) Brushes -->
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="SelectedInactiveBackgroundBrushKey"
                     StartPoint="0,0"
                     EndPoint="0,1">
    <GradientStop Color="#F8F8F8"
                  Offset="0" />
    <GradientStop Color="#E5E5E5"
                  Offset="1" />
</LinearGradientBrush>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="SelectedInactiveOuterBorderBrushKey"
                 Color="#D9D9D9" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="SelectedInactiveInnerBorderBrushKey"
                 Color="#F0F0F0" />

<!-- Supporting TreeViewItem Resources -->
<PathGeometry x:Key="TreeArrow">
    <PathGeometry.Figures>
        <PathFigureCollection>
            <PathFigure IsFilled="True"
                        StartPoint="0 0"
                        IsClosed="True">
                <PathFigure.Segments>
                    <PathSegmentCollection>
                        <LineSegment Point="0 6" />
                        <LineSegment Point="6 0" />
                    </PathSegmentCollection>
                </PathFigure.Segments>
            </PathFigure>
        </PathFigureCollection>
    </PathGeometry.Figures>
</PathGeometry>

<Style x:Key="ExpandCollapseToggleStyle"
       TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
    <Setter Property="Focusable"
            Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="Width"
            Value="16"/>
    <Setter Property="Height"
            Value="16"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                <Border 
                        x:Name="ExpandBorder"
                        Width="16"
                        Height="16"
                        Background="Transparent"
                        Padding="5,5,5,5">
                        <Path x:Name="ExpandPath"
                              Fill="Transparent"
                              Stroke="#FF989898"
                              Data="{StaticResource TreeArrow}">
                            <Path.RenderTransform>
                                <RotateTransform Angle="135"
                                                 CenterX="3"
                                                 CenterY="3"/>
                            </Path.RenderTransform>
                        </Path>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>

                    <!-- MouseOver, Collapsed -->
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" />
                            <Condition Property="IsChecked" Value="False" />
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>

                        <Setter TargetName="ExpandPath"
                                Property="Stroke"
                                Value="#FF1BBBFA"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="ExpandPath"
                                Property="Fill"
                                Value="Transparent"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="ExpandBorder"
                                Property="Background">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <VisualBrush>
                                    <VisualBrush.Visual>
                                        <Ellipse Height="1" Width="1" Fill="#FF1BBBFA">
                                            <Ellipse.Effect>
                                                <BlurEffect Radius="2" />
                                            </Ellipse.Effect>
                                        </Ellipse>
                                    </VisualBrush.Visual>
                                </VisualBrush>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>

                    </MultiTrigger>

                    <!-- MouseOver, Expanded -->
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" />
                            <Condition Property="IsChecked" Value="True" />
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>

                        <Setter TargetName="ExpandPath"
                                Property="Stroke"
                                Value="#FF1BBBFA"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="ExpandPath"
                                Property="Fill"
                                Value="#82DFFB"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="ExpandBorder"
                                Property="Background">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <VisualBrush>
                                    <VisualBrush.Visual>
                                        <Ellipse Height="1" Width="1" Fill="#FF1BBBFA">
                                            <Ellipse.Effect>
                                                <BlurEffect Radius="2" />
                                            </Ellipse.Effect>
                                        </Ellipse>
                                    </VisualBrush.Visual>
                                </VisualBrush>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>

                        <Setter TargetName="ExpandPath"
                                Property="RenderTransform">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <RotateTransform Angle="180"
                                                 CenterX="3"
                                                 CenterY="3"/>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>

                    </MultiTrigger>

                    <!-- No Mouseover, Expanded -->
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsChecked" Value="True" />
                            <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False" />
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter TargetName="ExpandPath"
                                Property="RenderTransform">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <RotateTransform Angle="180"
                                                 CenterX="3"
                                                 CenterY="3"/>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                        <Setter TargetName="ExpandPath"
                                Property="Fill"
                                Value="#FF595959"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="ExpandPath"
                                Property="Stroke"
                                Value="#FF262626"/>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<!-- TreeView Style (Fade toggle buttons in and out) -->
<Style x:Key="{x:Type TreeView}"
       TargetType="{x:Type TreeView}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True" >
            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                From="0.0" To="1.0" Duration="0:0:5"
                                />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </Trigger.EnterActions>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>


<!-- TreeViewItem Style -->
<Style x:Key="{x:Type TreeViewItem}"
       TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
            Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="Padding"
            Value="2,0" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">

                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="19"
                                          Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <ToggleButton x:Name="expander"
                                  Style="{StaticResource ExpandCollapseToggleStyle}"
                                  IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsExpanded, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                  ClickMode="Press" />
                    <Border x:Name="outerBorder"
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            CornerRadius="2"
                            SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <Border x:Name="innerBorder"
                                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                BorderThickness="1"
                                CornerRadius="1"
                                Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_Header"
                                              ContentSource="Header"
                                              HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                              SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                        </Border>
                    </Border>
                    <ItemsPresenter x:Name="itemsHost"
                                    Grid.Row="1"
                                    Grid.Column="1"
                                    Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
                </Grid>

                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsExpanded"
                             Value="false">
                        <Setter TargetName="itemsHost"
                                Property="Visibility"
                                Value="Collapsed" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="HasItems"
                             Value="false">
                        <Setter TargetName="expander"
                                Property="Visibility"
                                Value="Hidden" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger SourceName="outerBorder"
                             Property="IsMouseOver"
                             Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="outerBorder"
                                Property="BorderBrush"
                                Value="{StaticResource HoverOuterBorderBrushKey}" />
                        <Setter TargetName="innerBorder"
                                Property="Background"
                                Value="{StaticResource HoverBackgroundBrushKey}" />
                        <Setter TargetName="innerBorder"
                                Property="BorderBrush"
                                Value="{StaticResource HoverInnerBorderBrushKey}" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected"
                             Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="outerBorder"
                                Property="BorderBrush"
                                Value="{StaticResource SelectedActiveOuterBorderBrushKey}" />
                        <Setter TargetName="innerBorder"
                                Property="Background"
                                Value="{StaticResource SelectedActiveBackgroundBrushKey}" />
                        <Setter TargetName="innerBorder"
                                Property="BorderBrush"
                                Value="{StaticResource SelectedActiveInnerBorderBrushKey}" />
                    </Trigger>

                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsSelected"
                                       Value="true" />
                            <Condition Property="IsMouseOver"
                                       Value="true" />
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter TargetName="outerBorder"
                                Property="BorderBrush"
                                Value="{StaticResource HoverSelectedOuterBorderBrushKey}" />
                        <Setter TargetName="innerBorder"
                                Property="Background"
                                Value="{StaticResource HoverSelectedBackgroundBrushKey}" />
                        <Setter TargetName="innerBorder"
                                Property="BorderBrush"
                                Value="{StaticResource HoverSelectedInnerBorderBrushKey}" />
                    </MultiTrigger>

                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsSelected"
                                       Value="true" />
                            <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive"
                                       Value="false" />
                            <Condition Property="IsMouseOver"
                                       Value="false" />
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter TargetName="outerBorder"
                                Property="BorderBrush"
                                Value="{StaticResource SelectedInactiveOuterBorderBrushKey}" />
                        <Setter TargetName="innerBorder"
                                Property="Background"
                                Value="{StaticResource SelectedInactiveBackgroundBrushKey}" />
                        <Setter TargetName="innerBorder"
                                Property="BorderBrush"
                                Value="{StaticResource SelectedInactiveInnerBorderBrushKey}" />
                    </MultiTrigger>

                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled"
                             Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground"
                                Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The important parts are: TreeView Style, ExpandCollapseToggleStyle and TreeViewItem style.

**Here is the treeview:**

```
        <TreeView Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="2">
        <TreeViewItem Header="Item 1">
            <TreeViewItem Header="Subitem 1" />
            <TreeViewItem Header="Subitem 1" />
        </TreeViewItem>
        <TreeViewItem Header="Item 2">
            <TreeViewItem Header="Subitem 1" />
            <TreeViewItem Header="Subitem 1" />
        </TreeViewItem>
        <TreeViewItem Header="Item 3">
            <TreeViewItem Header="Subitem 1" />
            <TreeViewItem Header="Subitem 1" />
        </TreeViewItem>
        <TreeViewItem Header="Item 4">
            <TreeViewItem Header="Subitem 1" />
            <TreeViewItem Header="Subitem 1" />
        </TreeViewItem>
        <TreeViewItem Header="Item 5">
            <TreeViewItem Header="Subitem 1" />
            <TreeViewItem Header="Subitem 1" />
        </TreeViewItem>
        <TreeViewItem Header="Item 6">
            <TreeViewItem Header="Subitem 1" />
            <TreeViewItem Header="Subitem 1" />
        </TreeViewItem>
        <TreeViewItem Header="Item 7">
            <TreeViewItem Header="Subitem 1" />
            <TreeViewItem Header="Subitem 1" />
        </TreeViewItem>
        <TreeViewItem Header="Item 8">
            <TreeViewItem Header="Subitem 1" />
            <TreeViewItem Header="Subitem 1" />
        </TreeViewItem>
        <TreeViewItem Header="Item 9">
            <TreeViewItem Header="Subitem 1" />
            <TreeViewItem Header="Subitem 1" />
        </TreeViewItem>
    </TreeView>
```